# Couchbase JAVA SDK -Partialy update document

Tags: java, arrays, couchbase, crud, document

I have a document that has a data model corresponding to a user. 
The user has an adresses array, a phone array and an email array. 
I make CRUD operations on theses data using the Java SDK for Couchbase.
I have a constraint: I need to get all the document data in order to display data associated to the user. On the UI I can modify everything except the data contained by the arrays (phone, email and adresses).
How can I do to update only those data when I update the document ? 
When I try to use the JsonIgnore annotation on arrays method when serializing the user object, it removes them from the document when the JAVA couchbase method ***replace*** took place.

Is there a way to update partially documents with the JAVA SDK for couchbase ?

Comment: What version of couchbase are you using?  Partial updates of json documents is a new feature in Couchbase 4.5

http://blog.couchbase.com/2016/february/subdocument-couchbase-java-sdk

Comment: Thank you very much, it would do the job but we are using NoSQL DB to use flexible data sets. If some others data will join that data model, we'll need to modify that method. Do you know if there is something like exclude ? Because in this case is easier to exclude attributs from update that include attributs for updates